# Unknown linux process with random command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, debian, virus

I have a unknown process when I run `top`:

[image]

- When I kill the process it is coming again with another random name.
- when I check the rc.d levels and init.d there are many random name similar like this one and this one is also there.
- when I try to apt-get remove or anthing elses it is coming again.
- when I plug in network cable it is locking our whole network.

Do you have any idea how I can remove it?

What is this service/process?

This is the exe file, when I delete it, it is coming again too.

```
/proc/**pid**/exe => symbolic link to /usr/bin/hgmjzjkpxa
```

When i check "netstat -natp" there is an establisment foreign address is 98.126.251.114:2828. 
When i try to add rules to iptables, it is not working. 
But after trying and then restart this address change to 66.102.253.30:2828 this one.

OS is Debian Wheeze

Comment: Probably some botnet client (your machine is compromised). You have to find out how it is started. Utilities like `cruft` may come in handy to see what files do not belong to packages.

Comment: `ps l` will show you what the parent process is. Most likely, that'll tell you what is spawning this process. Look at the PPID column for the information you want. I wouldn't be so quick to declare this malware.

Comment: +1 to check the parent process. And if the file `/use/bin/hgmjzjkpxa` exists (could it be in /usr?) is it also a link, or something else interesting listed in `ls -la`, or viewed with `less` or `strings`?

Comment: there is no any parent process, it is looking like whoami process, there is one thing when i check "netstat -natp" there is an establisment foreign address is 98.126.251.114:2828. when i try to add rules to iptables, it is not working. But after trying and then restart this address change to 66.102.253.30:2828 this one. do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score 16):

This is known as the XORDDos Linux Trojan
The trick is to run `kill` with `-STOP` for the process to be paused so it doesn't create a new one.

```
`kill -STOP PROCESS_ID`
```

Comment: Great. This is exactly what I was seeking for.
Without reboot you really can not get rid of this virus if it is always being in memory. You even needn't to chmod any folders after stopping it - just remove the files and links and that's all.

Answer (score 15):

I have some experiences about this random 10bit string trojan, It will send lots of packets for SYN flood.

1. Cut down your network

The trojan has raw file coming from `/lib/libudev.so`, it will copy and fork again. It will also add `cron.hourly` job named `gcc.sh`,
then it will add initial script in your `/etc/rc*.d` (Debian, CentOS may be `/etc/rc.d/{init,rc{1,2,3,4,5}}.d`)

2. Use `root` to run the script below to change the folder privileges: `chmod 0000 /lib/libudev.so && rm -rf /lib/libudev.so && chattr +i /lib/`
3. Delete all `/etc/rc{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,S}.d` files which were created today, The name looks like `S01????????`.
4. Edit your crontab, delete the `gcc.sh` script in your `/etc/cron.hourly`, delete the `gcc.sh` file (`/etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh`)
   then add privileges for your crontab: `sed '/gcc.sh/d' /etc/crontab && chmod 0000 /etc/crontab && chattr +i /etc/crontab`
5. Use this command to check the latest file changes: `ls -lrt`

If you find any suspicious files named `S01xxxxxxxx` (or `K8xxxxxxxx`), delete it.

6. Then you should reboot without network.

Then the trojan should be cleaned and you can modify the folder privileges to the original values(`chattr -i /lib /etc/crontab`).

Comment: The instructions in this answer saved me. In spite of its age, this trojan still seems to be out in the wild. However, in step 4 there is an error, as the sed command does not actually change the file. It is simply modified, though: `sed '/gcc.sh/d' /etc/crontab > /etc/crontab.fixed && mv /etc/crontab.fixed /etc/crontab && chmod 0000 /etc/crontab && chattr +i /etc/crontab`.   Also, according to the link in @Colin Rosenthal's answer, infection is through brute-forced ssh password of root. So, in order to prevent reinfection, change or disable root password before restarting network.

Comment: `chattr -i /lib` returns `chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /lib` any clues? My /lib points to usr/lib

Comment: I'm also not able to restore network even after doing sudo apt install --reinstall libudev1

Comment: chmod 0000 /lib/libudev.so && rm -rf /lib/libudev.so && chattr +i /lib/ while running got permission denied, even runned with su and sudo

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet you a dollar it's https://blog.avast.com/2015/01/06/linux-ddos-trojan-hiding-itself-with-an-embedded-rootkit/ . All your symptoms are exactly as described.

Answer (score 1):

I to got this chicken virus, when i exposed default ports inorder to connect to remote access from my home machine.
in my case this site helped me out

## Steps

1) List the files under hourly cron. If you can see any .sh file, please open it.

```
root@vps-# ls -la /etc/cron.hourly/

++++++++++
CT-24007-bash-4.1# ls /etc/cron.hourly/
freshclam  gcc.sh
CT-24007-bash-4.1# 
++++++++++
```

2) If the .sh file is showing similar data as shown below, then it's a Virus program!!

```
root@vps-#  cat /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh

++++++++++
 cat /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh
#! / Bin / sh
PATH = / bin: / sbin: / usr / bin: / usr / sbin: / usr / local / bin: / usr / local / sbin: / usr / X11R6 / bin
for i in `cat / proc / net / dev | grep: | awk -F: {'print $ 1'}`; do ifconfig $ i up & done
cp /lib/libudev.so /lib/libudev.so.6
/lib/libudev.so.6
++++++++++
```

3) Now, please don't be hurry! Stay calm and easy :D

Do not delete gcc.sh or do not remove the  crontab. If you do delete or remove it, then another process will generate immediately.
You can either remove the culprit script or disable it. [ I prefer to disable it to show the proof to the customer ]

```
root@vps-# rm -f /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh;
```

OR

```
root@vps- #  chmod 0 /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh; chattr +ia /etc/cron.hourly/gcc.sh;  chattr + i /etc/crontab
```

4) Use top command to view virus or malicious file ( Eg :"mtyxkeaofa" ) PID  is 16621, do not directly kill the program, otherwise it will again produce, but to stop its operation use the below command.

---

```
root@vps- # kill -STOP 16621
```

## Delete files within /etc/init.d. or disable it [ I prefer to disable it to show the proof to the customer ]

```
root@vps-# find /etc -name '* mtyxkeaofa *' | xargs rm -f
```

OR

```
chmod 0 /usr/bin/mtyxkeaofa; 
chmod 0 /etc/init.d/mtyxkeaofa; 
chattr +ia /usr/bin/mtyxkeaofa; 
chattr +ia /etc/init.d/mtyxkeaofa;
```

---

6) Delete /usr/bin inside archives.

```
root@vps-# rm -f /usr/bin/mtyxkeaofa;
```

7) Check /usr/bin archives recent changes, the virus can also be deleted if the other suspect is the same directory.

```
root@vps-# ls -lt /usr/bin | head
```

8) Now kill the malicious program, it will not produce.

```
root@vps-# pkill mtyxkeaofa
```

9) Remove the virus body.

```
root@vps-# rm -f /lib/libudev.so
```

This trojan is also know as Chinese Chicken Multiplatform DoS botnets Trojan,  Unix - Trojan.DDoS_XOR-1, Embedded rootkit,

> Note: If you are unable to find .sh file, you may please install ClamAV, RKHunter and check logs/report to find the suspicious/malicious

## link to the actual site

https://admin-ahead.com/forum/server-security-hardening/unix-trojan-ddos_xor-1-chinese-chicken-multiplatform-dos-botnets-trojan/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/945643)

Comment: will update that here

Answer (score 0):

For me there were two options:

1. For the trojan which is messing with files in /usr/bin I only did this:
   echo > /lib/libudev.so
   Kill the trojan PID
2. For the one messing with /bin (here there were always 5-10 processes running for a fraction
   chattr +i /bin and follow the steps mentioned by rainysia

Answer (score 0):

We also faces the same issue, Our servers are also Hacked and i found that they brute forced the ssh login and got succes and injected  trojan in our system .

**Following are the details :**

less /var/log/secure | grep 'Failed password' | grep '222.186.15.26' | wc -l 
37772 started

and got access on below time : 
 Accepted password for root from 222.186.15.26 port 65418 ssh2

And as per IP Location Finder this ip belongs to somewhere in china .

**Corrective Steps :**  please follow steps given by : @rainysia

**Preventive Steps :**  :

1. According to me some notification managemnet should be there when someone tried to ssh or acces your server and fail many times .
2. Network Rate controllers should be there if you are using any cloud platform like aws,gcp,azure etc ...

Comment: but first, disallow root access via ssh, disallow any ssh access with password, allow only access via ssh with keys