# Is this malware?

Tags: linux, malware, malware-removal, rootkit

I have a machine running Linux Mint (qiana). I noticed it was often slow and when I looked at top I found

```
PID    USER    PR   NI     VIRT     RES    SHR  S   %CPU  %MEM      TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                         
30171  root     0  -20    69148    2192    212  S  142.0   0.1  731:27.56  wfoxqueneq                                                                                      
17     root    20    0        0       0      0  S    6.2   0.0    3:13.28  ksoftirqd/1                                                                                     
2506  colin    20    0  1884492  165752  41136  S    6.2   4.2   33:01.48  xbmc.bin
```

I don't recognise the mysterious process "wfoxqueneq" (I reniced it to -20 myself, btw). If I kill it, it eventually comes back, with a different name. There is an executable /usr/bin/wfoxqueneq which disappears when I kill the process.  According to ps, the command line for the program is "uptime".

```
colin@redick ~ $ ps auxww|grep 30171
colin    28039  0.0  0.0  11744   912 pts/7    S+   10:15   0:00 grep --colour=auto 30171
root     30171 96.1  0.0  69148  2192 ?        S<sl Feb16 736:57 uptime
```

So is this some sort of malware? And if so, can I do anything about it less drastic than a reinstall?

Comment: Already asked at http://superuser.com/questions/877896/ .

Comment: What programs/updates have you done lately? Anything from non-standard (non-Ubuntu or non-Mint) sources or PPA's, or download and ran any executable files? Can you show the parent PID's (PPID's) to see what process is starting them? (`ps -ef` or `ps -ely` should show them) then `grep` for he parent PID/PPID too

Comment: mystery folders you didn't create yourself is indeed a sign of malware.  Nuke from orbit

Comment: Pretty sure it was this: https://blog.avast.com/2015/01/06/linux-ddos-trojan-hiding-itself-with-an-embedded-rootkit/ - the cronjob, rc-scripts, and ten-letter executable name were all there. Nuked as suggested - and our home network is suddenly stable again. Live and learn.